# Change command string of FormFlow Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I'm using **FormFlow** to build my bot and as we know that, the **FormFlow** is set some commands in English by default (help, back, quit, etc...), but because my customer doesn't know English well, so how can we change it to another string. I've read about **FormConfiguration** class and it seem can resolve my problem but I can't find any example about this. So is it possible to change it and how can we do that?
Thanks
[FormConfiguration class](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/db8/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_form_configuration.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add another keyword for Quit in FormFlows - Bot Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749150/add-another-keyword-for-quit-in-formflows-bot-framework)

Comment: Thanks for suggested me. I'll try it.

Comment: You need to change your localization by using CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture. Here's a link: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html. The information is about half-way down the page.