# BotBuilder: Customize Formflow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

can you suggest me which configuration need to be set to change the "What do you want to change?" after saying no in confirmation at the end of the formflow?
Thx

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Please provide what you tried so far

Answer (score 2):

That message is part of the of the [TemplateNavigation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/search?p=1&q=TemplateNavigation&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) resources and a `Template` in the [FormConfiguration](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/IFormBuilder.cs#L245) class is defined with the `TemplateUsage.Navigation` as seen [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/IFormBuilder.cs#L371).

The way to go is partially explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749150/add-another-keyword-for-quit-in-formflows-bot-framework/40749224#40749224) with the only difference that you need to change the `Template` to look for and that you don't need to change any command of the `FormConfiguration`

```
private static IFormBuilder<T> CreateCustomForm<T>() where T : class
{
    var form = new FormBuilder<T>();
    var templateAttribute = form.Configuration.Template(TemplateUsage.Navigation);
    var patterns = templateAttribute.Patterns;
    patterns[0] = "My prompt";
    templateAttribute.Patterns = patterns;

    return form;
}
```