# Customizing the Navigation Form after my form's confirmation dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I've defined a custom `MessageDelegate` to pass to `.Confirm(...)` on my `FormBuilder`. (See screenshot.)

My issue is that I'd like to customize the Navigation menu that appears when a user selects "No" on the `Confirm` dialog. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848137/botbuilder-customize-formflow) SO post which seems to be heading in the right direction, but I want more customization.  I still want the list of buttons to appear, but I want to be able to specify which buttons appear/don't appear, as well as the text on each button, rather than having it auto-populated by FormFlow.

For example:

- In my use case, I have a `HasMiddleName` field followed by a `MiddleName` field that only appears to the user if the `HasMiddleName` field receives a "Yes" answer. I want the Navigation to only show "Middle Name" similar to how it shows First/Last. And if the user selects the Middle Name, I want it to redirect to the `HasMiddleName` part of the form.
- Another tweak is that I'd like to be able to format the Date of Birth to show only `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I tried to play around with using the [Pattern language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-pattern-language?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), but couldn't get it work... Is what I want possible? If I manually create the dialog I'd like to show how can I associate that with the FormFlow's navigation?

[image: Custom Confirm and Subsequent Navigation Menu]

Comment: So your form's navigation step is correctly omitting the MiddleName field in that case, but you also want it to omit the HasMiddleName field in all cases. Is that right? If so, what would the user click on to navigate to the MiddleName step? Or are you saying you want the MiddleName field to be included in the navigation step even when HasMiddleName is false? With no value for MiddleName, would it say "Middle Name()" or what?

Comment: "the MiddleName field to be included in the navigation step even when HasMiddleName is false" - Yes! This is what I'd like. Then I imagine the button text would read "Middle Name(None)" With "None" in italics if that's possible.

Comment: Perhaps just the `Date Of Birth` formatting is simpler to answer (and it may lead me to the other answers.)  Is there a way to format the Date Of Birth button to read `MM/dd/yyyy` rather than including the time as well?

Comment: Yeah that's easy. You just use `[Template(TemplateUsage.NavigationFormat, "Date of Birth ({:d})")]` on your `DateTime` field

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, posted comments on your answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation step is a bit tricky to customize, so I've come up with a solution that lets you work around that. The trick is to make sure the `MiddleName` field is inactive when the navigation step rolls around and to have the `HasMiddleName` field masquerade as the `MiddleName` field so that clicking on it will take you to the `HasMiddleName` field.

```
// We want our HasMiddleName field to be treated as the "Middle Name" field for navigation purposes
[Describe("Middle Name"), Prompt("Does the dependent have a middle name?"), Template(TemplateUsage.NavigationFormat, "{&}({MiddleName})", FieldCase = CaseNormalization.None)]
public bool HasMiddleName { get; set; }

// I'm showing you how to use the "Unspecified" template but for some reason it doesn't work in the navigation step.
// Also, be careful about giving two fields the same description. It works in this case because of the tricks we're using.
[Optional, Describe("Middle Name"), Prompt("Please enter middle name {||}"), Template(TemplateUsage.NoPreference, "None"), Template(TemplateUsage.Unspecified, "None")]
public string MiddleName { get; set; }

[Template(TemplateUsage.NavigationFormat, "{&}({:d})", FieldCase = CaseNormalization.None)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

public static IForm<MyClass> BuildForm()
{
    var builder = new FormBuilder<MyClass>()
        .Field(new FieldReflector<MyClass>(nameof(HasMiddleName)).SetNext((value, state) =>
        {
            // This NextDelegate will execute after the user enters a value for HasMiddleName
            bool didTheySayYes = (bool)value;
            // If MiddleName is inactive it will be skipped over
            state._isMiddleNameActive = didTheySayYes;

            if (didTheySayYes)
            {
                // We need to explicitly navigate to the MiddleName field
                // or else it will go back to the confirmation step
                // if a middle name had already been entered
                return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(MiddleName) });
            }
            else
            {
                // We want to clear the middle name in case one had been entered before
                state.MiddleName = null;
                // This will go to either the DateOfBirth field or the confirmation step
                // since the MiddleName field will be inactive in this case
                return new NextStep();
            }
        }))
        .Field(new FieldReflector<MyClass>(nameof(MiddleName)).SetActive(state => state._isMiddleNameActive))
        .Field(new FieldReflector<MyClass>(nameof(DateOfBirth)))
        .Confirm(async state =>
        {
            // We're making sure MiddleName is inactive at the confirmation step
            // so it won't be visible in the navigation step,
            // but since we're not changing the MiddleName field
            // it can still be retrieved from the form's result
            state._isMiddleNameActive = false;
            return new PromptAttribute("Ok. Is this correct? {||}");
        });

    return builder.Build();
}

// This private field isn't included in the form
private bool _isMiddleNameActive;
```

On the other hand, there's another avenue to explore if you really want control over what buttons show up in the navigation step. The above code should serve you well but I feel like I should briefly mention this other trick because I wrote a [post](https://github.com/v-kydela/BotBlog/blob/master/Blog%20-%20Making%20your%20own%20Prompter.md) about how to do it. If you make your own prompter, you can check if the field name equals `__navigation__` in your `PromptAsync` delegate and then generate a message accordingly. Keep in mind that you'd still have to use some of the first solution to make sure clicking on "Middle Name" takes you to the `HasMiddleName` field.

Comment: `// I'm showing you how to use the "Unspecified" template but for some reason it doesn't work in the navigation step.` - Is this a bug?

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm understanding what's happening here: The MiddleName field is marked as inactive so it doesn't appear on the navigation. Then the HasMiddleName field DOES appear with the desc "Middle Name" (that's the masquerading part you referred to) Additionally, we set up a delegate so that as we're initially collecting the data, the MiddleName prompt only appears if the HasMiddleName value was true. Very clever, (and somewhat hacky) solution!